# Bash / Python: Organization of several scripts

Tags: python, linux, bash, scripting, organization

I have built a photo booth on a raspberry pi. It works fantastic! But after some coding I now have a problem organizing my scripts. At the moment all scripts are launched via "lxterminal -e". So every script has it's own terminal window and everything runs simultaneously. I ask myself if this can be done in a more efficient way.

The basic function of the photo booth: People press a remote button, take a picture, picture is being shown on the built-in tft.

> **start.sh** --> is being executed automatically after booting. It prepares the system, , sets up the camera and brings it in tethered mode. After all that it launches the other, following scripts:
>
> **system-watchdog.sh** --> checks continuously if one of the physical buttons on the photo booth is being pressed, to reboot or go into setup mode. It's an ever-lasting-while-loop.
>
> **sync.sh** --> syncs the captured photo to some folders, where they are modified for beeing printed. Also an ever-lasting-while-loop.
>
> **backup.sh** --> copies all taken pictures to a usb device as a backup. This is a cronjob, every 5 minutes.
>
> **temp-logger.sh** --> Logs the temperature of the CPU continuously, because I had heat-problems.

The cpu is running constantly at about 20-40%. Maybe with some optimization I could run on viewer scripts and less cpu usage.

Any suggestions what I could use to organize the scripts in a better way?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

> **sync.sh** --> syncs the captured photo to some folders, where they are modified for 1. being shown on the second screen, 2. upload to
>   dropbox and 3. being printed. Also an ever-lasting-while-loop.
>
> **terminal-sync.sh** --> copies the taken photos to the
>   second-screen-terminal, where they are shown in a gallery. It's also
>   an ever-lasting-while-loop.

For these, you can use inotifywait to wait for file availability before processing the file.

You should check using top, which script actually consuming CPU and why. Once you identify the script and why it consume CPU, then you can start finding optimized way to do the same job